# difference between two times Laravel Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to check difference between two times in Laravel (the day is not needed)

```
Carbon::createFromTimeString($this->debut)
        ->diffInHours(Carbon::createFromTimeString($this->fin))
```

if  `$this->debut = '08:00:00'` and `$this->fin = '02:00:00'` the expected result is 18 but I have 6

How can I get the correct difference please

Comment: You have to compare the results the other way to get 18 I believe. If that doesn't work, you might need to add the date

Comment: @RobBiermann I don't want to save the date, I just need the begin time and the end time, the unexpected result occure when the end time is after 00:00, so it is the next day, but `diffinHours` treats it like numbers `8- 2 = 6 `

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you have to set date at least relatively for the correct calculation:

```
$this->debut = Carbon::today()->hour(8);
$this->fin = Carbon::tomorrow()->hour(2);

$diff = $this->debut->diffInHours($this->fin); // 18
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be that the time difference should always be positive. If the second parameter of Carbon::diffInHours is set to false, the result is not absolute. In this case, the intermediate result is -6. If the difference is negative, 24 hours are added.

```
$start = '08:00:00';
$end = '02:00:00';
$hours = Carbon::create($start)->diffInHours($end, false);
if($hours < 0) $hours += 24;
echo $hours;  //18
```

[Try them yourself.](https://try-carbon.herokuapp.com/?hide-output-gutter%26output-left-padding=10&theme=tomorrow_night&border=none&radius=4&v-padding=15&input=%24start%20%3D%20%2708%3A00%3A00%27%3B%0D%0A%24end%20%3D%20%2702%3A00%3A00%27%3B%0D%0A%24hours%20%3D%20Carbon%3A%3Acreate%28%24start%29-%3EdiffInHours%28%24end%2C%20false%29%3B%0D%0Aif%28%24hours%20%3C%200%29%20%24hours%20%2B%3D%2024%3B%0D%0Aecho%20%24hours%3B%20%20%2F%2F18&token=live-editor-120)